# 405 Method Not Allowed for POST and PUT in laravel application

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, http-status-code-405

I'm trying to drop and resize an event in fullcalendar in laravel, but when I move the event, I have 405 Method Not Allowed error message!..

**My web.php file:**

```html
Route::get('calendar', 'FullCalendarController@index');
Route::get('/load-events', 'EventController@loadEvents')->name('routeLoadEvents');
Route::put('/events-update', 'EventController@update')->name('routeEventUpdate');
```

**My blade.php file:**

```html
<div id='calendar' 
data-route-load-events="{{route('routeLoadEvents')}}" 
data-route-events-update="{{route('routeEventUpdate')}}"></div>
```

**My .js file:**

```js
$(function (){
    $.ajaxSetup({
       headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
       }
    });
});

function sendEvent(route, data_){
    $.ajax({
        url: route,
        data: data_,
        method: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json){
            if(json){
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    });
}

function routeEvents(route){
    return document.getElementById('calendar').dataset[route];
}

eventDrop: function(element){

        let start = moment( element.event.start ).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        let end = moment( element.event.end ).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

        let newEvent = {
            _method: 'PUT',
            id: element.event.id,
            start: start,
            end: end
        };

        sendEvent(routeEvents('routeEventUpdate'), newEvent);

      },
```

Answer (score 0):

So there are really only two types of request that Laravel really understands:

`POST` & `GET`

A `PUT` request is a `POST` request with a method of `PUT`.

What laravel is looking for is a `_method` parameter in the request telling it what type of request this is. in your case `_method: PUT`.

---

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: route,
    data: data_,
    method: 'PUT',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(json){
        if(json){
            location.reload();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You put your "put" method in your payload-data, this wont be recocnized by the AJAX Function. Try adding the method as an Argument

function sendEvent(route, data_, sendMethod){
...
method: sendMethod,
...

**And call i via**

```
sendEvent(routeEvents('routeEventUpdate'), newEvent, 'PUT');
```

Comment: I have always the same error: PUT method not allowed